# Need a very simple, working file uploader

Tags: jquery, html, css, upload

I've tried so many things from uploadify to jquery-file-upload and many many more and I can't seem to make them work! I have my website on localhost and I want the uploaded files to all go into a folder but nothing seems to send the files to the folder. I'm only using html/css & jquery. I'm not very familiar at all with PHP yet which is part of the reason I probably can't get these to work. I would show the coding but I've deleted everything to do with the uploader just to have a fresh start.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is you can't achieve this without any server side coding.

The jQuery upload plugin will do it's job in client side, but you still need some coding on server side to accept and save the upload content.

Based on what web server you are deploying your web site to, you could use PHP/ASP.NET, Java, etc.